# codeigniter, view template string to DomDocument operating

Tags: php, codeigniter, domdocument

I have a php file in application\views\article.php

article.php content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> test div1 </div>
<div> test div2 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use $this->load->view() to load article.php template and use DomDocument to get dom.

```
$html=$this->load->view('article','',TRUE);
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);      
echo $doc->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0));
// or echo $doc->saveXML();
```

have the error message:
Message: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : meta in Entity, line: 4

but whe I use this:

```
$html='<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html prefix=\'og: http://ogp.me/ns#\'>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>   test div1 </div>
    <div> test div2 </div>
    <p>Directory </p>
    </body>
    </html>';

  $doc->loadHTML($html);         
  echo $doc->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0));
  // or echo $doc->saveXML();
```

this is success.

gettype($html) to two methods of $html, both are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hide the warning with

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Or:

```
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

The warning is because the HTML returned by `$this->load->view('article','',TRUE);` is invalid, loadHTML() resolve this but show the warnings.

[Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/es/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

Comment: why? This $this->load->view('article','',TRUE) is invalid?

Comment: Maybe unescape chars, try see the string of this HTML with a simple `var_dump($doc->loadHTML($html));`  what show you?

Comment: unescape chars? var_dump($doc->loadHTML($html)) show more error message: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : meta in Entity, line: 4.....line:9, five messages. var_dump(@$doc->loadHTML($html)) show bool(true)

Comment: Sorry, `var_dump($html)` is the correct code, see the raw string that CI return in the function $this->load->view and verify the structure of this.